# What is this small drain pipe in my garage wall?

Tags: water, pipe, drainage, flooding, leaking

I have a drainage pipe (PVC - looks like the air unit/water heater one) of some sort that is in my garage it doesn't belong to the water heater or the air unit I know where those are. I cannot think of anything else it would belong to.. it looks like it goes into my kitchen.. this morning it created a puddle in the garage but it has never done this before.

[image]

Comment: A picture would be excellent. If you can just supply a link to some free image uploading service then we can embed it in your question.

Comment: Sorry I just added it.. my phone wouldn't let me add it when I made the post.

Comment: I assume your kitchen is behind that wall where the pipe exists? What's above your garage? Is it an attic?

Comment: Thank you this was the problem..

Comment: Nice. I turned my comment into an answer so if you found it useful then please feel free to accept it =)

Answer (score 1):

Is that 3/4 inch PVC? If so then it's very likely a backup drain line for a furnace and/or evaporator coil (A/C). It might be dumping on your garage floor on purpose to warn you that the main drain line is clogged. I would expect it to drip whenever your A/C is turned on.